# has_many through roles and scopes on the third model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Lets say I have movies, people and movies_people

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies_people
  has_many :movies, through: :movies_people

class Movies < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies_people
  has_many :people, through: :movies_people


class MoviesPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :person
end
```

The table `movies_people` has a role attribute, where I want to store the person's job in the movie.  Right now I can do things like this in the console:

```
u = User.first
m = Movie.first
m.people << u
```

then find the right movies_people entry and set 'role'

retrieving looks like this:

```
m.people.where(movies_people: {role: :actor})
```

---

**Whats the best way to:**

1. Save the role (***to the third table***) when joining people to movies?
2. Return all the actors in a movie vs. all the directors vs. all the writers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to create `Roles` which contains a list of existing roles and a `MovieRole`
class which joins Movies, People and Roles.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_roles, class_name: "MovieRole"
  has_many :roles, through: :movie_roles
  has_many :people, through: :movie_roles
end

class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_roles, class_name: "MovieRole"
  has_many :movies, through: :movie_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :movie_roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_roles, class_name: "MovieRole"
  has_many :people, through: :movie_roles
  has_many :movies, through: :movie_roles
end

class MovieRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :people
  belongs_to :role
end
```

All the relations are stores in `movie_roles` which is a three way join table:

```
class CreateMovieRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :movie_roles do |t|
      t.references :movie, index: true
      t.references :people, index: true
      t.references :role, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Some examples of how you could query this association:

```
@roles = Movie.find_by(title: 'Godzilla').roles
@directors = People.joins(:roles).where(roles: {name: 'Director'})
@directed_by_eastwood = Movie.joins(:people, :roles)
                               .merge(Role.where(name: 'Director'))
                               .merge(People.where(name: 'Clint Eastwood'))
```

### Added:

To associate a person with a movie you would:

```
MovieRole.create(people: person, movie: movie, role: role)
```

But you will want to setup convinience methods like:

```
class People < ActiveRecord::Base
  def add_role(role, movie)
    role = Role.find_by(name: role) unless role.is_a?(Role)
    MovieRole.create(people: self, movie: movie, role: role)
  end 
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def add_cast(role, person)
    role = Role.find_by(name: role) unless role.is_a?(Role)
    MovieRole.create(people: person, movie: self, role: role)
  end 
end
```

Comment: One advantage here vs @alejandro-babio s otherwise acceptable answer is that you can list Roles (without the headaches of a distinct query), and you can also query roles without doing `MoviesPerson.where(role: 'Fluffer')`.

Comment: I think I'm going to do a combination of both answers but picking this one for comprehensiveness.  There's definitely a limited number of unique roles so I don't think my case needs another table, I will probably just store the possible roles in an array on MoviePerson.

Comment: I guess that works so long that adding roles is a developer concern.

Comment: @parpapirtiger, can you actually do @directors = Role.where(name: 'Director').people?

I ended up implementing the three-way join table but I'm getting "NoMethodError: undefined method `people' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Role id: 1, name: "Director">]>"

Comment: Ooops, guess I should have tested that one. Doing a join query `People.joins(:roles).where(roles: {name: 'Director'})` does however produce the intended result. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

To save the role, just:

```
person = Person.find(person_id)
movie = Movie.find(movie_id)

movie.movies_people.create(person: person, role: :actor)
```

To retrieve by role,

```
movie = Movie.includes(:people).where(id: movie_id).where(movies_people: {role: :actor})
```

**Edit**: I don't advice to add a roles table, unless you need it. I follow the [agile principles](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html), in this case: "Simplicity--the art of maximizing the amount of work not done--is essential."